# In-App Review, whether it will show the review dialog if the user reviewed the app from playstore?

Tags: android, google-play

I implemented the in-app review feature and it bugs me that there is no proper documentation regarding quotas or corner-case scenarios.

Suppose if the user **has already reviewed the app by going to the app page from the play store**, will the user be prompted with the in-app review dialog or not?

It is such a simple case and should be in the documentation.

Comment: it's absurd indeed that such an important peace of info not mentioned in the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they will not be shown the review dialog.

This is from personal experience and the following line in the [Test in-app reviews](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test) part of the documentation:

> When using an internal test track, the following conditions must be
> met:
>
> 4. The user account does not currently have a review for the app.

With my app, the test users had to delete their old review (submitted through the play store) in order to be shown the dialog.

Comment: And it will be the same in the production as well?

Comment: Yes. Tried it with friends.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for this information.

Comment: Btw, I am testing this using "internal in-app sharing" and the submit button is disabled so I am not able to test it properly. I think internal test track functioning is different from this.

Comment: Yes, the internal sharing has the button disabled.

Comment: Okay. Do you know the quota limit right now for the dialog to re-appear?

Comment: No sorry. I've set mine up to only ask once. From what I've read its a couple of months.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for help

Comment: is it possible to know that the dialog is not appearing for a user? I could redirect them to the play store page if not showing.

Comment: Probably. Check the requestReviewFlow() task if it is successful and if it isn't redirect them. Should work but haven't tried. Not replying anymore since this isn't what comments are for. Good luck.